# JWplayer file could not be played in google chrome

Tags: html, wordpress, jwplayer

So my jwplayer is utilised as a wordpress plugin and will play mp3 files on browsers that don't use the html5 side of jwplayer but when i use chrome or mobile device the file won't play and I get the error: "Error loading media: file could not be played". Any ideas why this wouldn't play the mp3?

Comment: Maybe you are using a protocol or file format which is not supported by the browser. Please show your code and give information about the file encoding.

Comment: The code is a wordpress plugin with shortcode but it's just a standard mp3 file

Comment: Is there a URL we can look at?

Comment: managed to get some support elsewhere saying it is likely a codec issue with the files. will test and check. site is local dev atm so no test :(

Comment: You should also check server mime types!

Comment: how do I check mime-types...? I've now tried mp3, mp4 as audio and m4a but none work in chrome just get the same error